# How do you assert that an object has a certain method in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, exception, assertions

How do you assert that an object has a certain method in c++? Or throw an exception when you try to call it and it isn't there? Is this what I should be doing to handle my problem?

I have a container class with a custom object inside of it. In a container method, I want to call the 'smaller' object's method, but I need to make sure it exists first.

I probably shouldn't make the desired method a pure virtual function in this class because it is also used in other ways by different container classes that don't need it to be this way. Right?

Comment: c++  doesn't have *"dynamic method call"*. If you try to call a non-existent method, your program won't compile.

Comment: Pure virtual methods are the way this is normally done in C++.

Comment: You could use templates.  Pass in a container holding T.  If you call a method on T that doesn't exist, the program won't compile.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] of what you are talking about.  Describing code when you don't know what you need to do is less clear than writing code and sharing it.  If pseudo code, the less pseudo the better.

Comment: Objects do not have methods. Classes have methods. Exceptions are thrown at runtime. Deciding whether a method exists or not happens at compile time.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I didn't know that. Do you just call it a member function if it's an object's?

Comment: @Taylor: Actually, "method" is not C++ terminology at all; it's always called "member function". But what I meant is that it does not make sense to somehow test the existence of a member function of an *object*. It's the type which defines the available member functions, not the object. When virtual functions are involved, an object may have a dynamic type in addition to its static type. But it's still all about the types, not the individual objects. This is in stark contrast to e.g. JavaScript, which features methods on an object level.

Comment: "Or throw an exception when you try to call it and it isn't there?" C++ is a statically typed compiled language. The issue you are describing simply does not arise in C++. In C++ you cannot even attempt to call something that "isn't there". You program will never compile in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to do. Show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not provide a runtime-check if a method exists for a particular object at hand. But you can overcome this in two principal ways: (1) use (pure) virtual functions at some common base class level, or (2) check the type of the object at hand.

**(1) pure virtual function approach:**

```
class ContainerObject {
  ...
  virtual void somethingSpecific() = 0;
}
class MyContainerObject : public ContainerObject {
  ...
  virtual void somethingSpecific() {  ... }
}
```

Thereby, if you get a pointer to an object of type `ContainerObject`, you can rely on the existence of member function `somethingSpecific()`; Note that class `ContainerObject` is abstract, as it contains a pure virtual function, i.e. a virtual member function without implementation:

```
ContainerObject *o = someContainer.getSomeObject();
o->somethingSpecific(); // compiler checks existence of `somethingSpecific`.
```

**(2) a type check approach:**

However, if you do not want to expose `somethingSpecific` at a general level, you could use type checks, e.g. with dynamic casts. Suppose a similar example as above, yet without the pure virtual function `somethingSpecific` at the level of `ContainerObject` class:

```
class ContainerObject {
  ...
  virtual void anyOtherVirtualFunction();
}
class MyContainerObject : public ContainerObject {
  ...
  virtual void somethingSpecific() {  ... }
}
```

The runtime type check based on dynamic cast then tries to interpret the object returned by `getSomeObject` as a `MyContainerObject`:

```
MyContainerObject *o = dynamic_cast<MyContainerObject*>(someContainer.getSomeObject());
if (o != nullptr)  // does o point to a MyContainerObject?
  o->somethingSpecific();
```

Note that `getSomeObject` might return an object other than a `MyContainerObject`. In this case, the result of the dynamic cast would be null. Hence, if the result is not null, then you can rely that `o` points to a `MyContainerObject`-instance (which implements `somethingSpecific`).

Note further, that dynamic cast requires that polymorphism is in place, which means that the base class `ContainerObject` must have at least one virtual member function (`anyOtherVirtualFunction` in this example).

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sfinae tricks to write a trait that has a static member value that is `true` if an expression of your choice can be compiled, but `false` if it can't.
I got this trick from a presentation at the 2015 CppCon,
The presentation is called

> C++ Metaprogramming/C++ Metaprogramming by Fedor Pikus

Here are the links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZi6QqZSbFg

https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Presentations/

Here's my take on a header based on this technique:

```
#ifndef SU3_EXPRESSION_TRAITS_HH
#define SU3_EXPRESSION_TRAITS_HH

#include <type_traits>

// DEFINE_TRAIT from:
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZi6QqZSbFg
// https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Presentations/
// C++ Metaprogramming/C++ Metaprogramming - Fedor Pikus - CppCon 2015.pdf

#define DEFINE_UNARY_TRAIT(NAME, EXPR) \
template <typename T> struct NAME { \
  typedef char yes; \
  typedef char no[2]; \
  template <typename U> static auto f(U&& x) -> decltype(EXPR, NAME::yes()); \
  template <typename U> static no&  f(...); \
  enum { value = sizeof(NAME::f<T>(std::declval<T>())) \
              == sizeof(NAME::yes) }; \
};

#define DEFINE_BINARY_TRAIT(NAME, EXPR) \
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct NAME { \
  typedef char yes; \
  typedef char no[2]; \
  template <typename U1, typename U2> \
  static auto f(U1&& x1, U2&& x2) -> decltype(EXPR, NAME::yes()); \
  template <typename U1, typename U2> static no& f(...); \
  enum { value = sizeof(NAME::f<T1,T2>(std::declval<T1>(),std::declval<T2>())) \
              == sizeof(NAME::yes) }; \
};

#define DEFINE_VARIADIC_TRAIT(NAME, EXPR) \
template <typename T, typename... TT> struct NAME { \
  typedef char yes; \
  typedef char no[2]; \
  template <typename U, typename... UU> \
  static auto f(U&& x, UU&&... xx) -> decltype(EXPR, NAME::yes()); \
  template <typename U, typename... UU> static no& f(...); \
  enum { value = sizeof(NAME::f<T,TT...>(std::declval<T>(),std::declval<TT>()...)) \
              == sizeof(NAME::yes) }; \
};

namespace su3 {

DEFINE_UNARY_TRAIT(has_op_pre_increment,  ++x)
DEFINE_UNARY_TRAIT(has_op_post_increment, x++)
DEFINE_UNARY_TRAIT(has_op_pre_decrement,  --x)
DEFINE_UNARY_TRAIT(has_op_post_decrement, x--)

DEFINE_BINARY_TRAIT(has_op_plus_eq, x1+=x2)
DEFINE_BINARY_TRAIT(has_op_minus_eq, x1-=x2)

DEFINE_VARIADIC_TRAIT(is_callable, x(xx...))
DEFINE_VARIADIC_TRAIT(is_constructible, T(xx...))

} // end namespace

#endif
```

With the header included, you can define a new trait for a new expression with one of the `DEFINE_*_TRAIT` macros. The defined traits can be used like this:

```
std::cout << su3::has_op_pre_increment<int>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << su3::is_constructible<std::string,const char*>::value << std::endl;
```

Or to check if a contained has an `emplace_back()` member function,

```
DEFINE_VARIADIC_TRAIT(has_emplace_back, x.emplace_back(xx...))
std::cout << has_emplace_back<std::vector<int>,double>::value << std::endl;
```

This will print `true` if `std::vector<int>().emplace_back(42.)` is a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (from Walter Brown: [Part I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY), [Part II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE)) is to use [void_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

Here's an example of a trait that checks if you can call `emplace_back` member function:

```
template <typename... T> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template <typename... T> using void_t = typename make_void<T>::type;

template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_size : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct has_size<T,
  void_t<decltype( std::declval<T&>().size() )>
> : std::true_type { };

int main() {
  std::cout << has_size<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This approach is a lot more concise than the one in my previous answer.